# ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions. in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

Here is my android home & path

```
manish@manish-Vostro-2520:~/hello$ echo $PATH

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin:/home/manish/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/manish/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

manish@manish-Vostro-2520:~/hello$ $ANDROID_HOME

bash: /home/manish/Android/Sdk: Is a directory
```

but still when I execute `sudo cordova build` i am getting :

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/manish/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/manish/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Here is ~/.bashrc entry

```
#android path
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to .bashrc file by adding:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/manish/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```

Note that existing shell won't have this path set, so it's recommended to restart your Linux machine once after adding those to the environment.

Comment: or simply sourcing the bashrc file. no need to resort to harsh measure

Comment: how is this different from my export

Comment: Yeah, you did not mention that earlier, so I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, try the following command line:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/< your installation location>/android-sdk-linux    
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are trying to build as a superuser.  The best answer is to not use sudo while building, and simply use `cordova build`.  Depending on how you setup node, this might not work for you.

Alternatively you could modify the bashrc located at `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
sudo -s 
//login with superuser credentials
//then use an editor to modify, or just append to the file echo "export ANDROID... >> etc/bash.bashrc
vim /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then simply add as other suggested:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```

Comment: if i run `cordova build` i got this `cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):/home/manish/hello/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/manish/hello/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js

rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/manish/hello/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /home/manish/hello/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js
`

Comment: Maybe because you created the project with `sudo cordova create` ? Want to run an `ls -l` on those files and see who owns them?

Answer (score 0):

for Mac:
go to the Android Studio and `configure/SDK Manager` get t`he Android SDK Location`.
then:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=Android SDK location
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```